# Java web app: prevent a slash from being added to the path?

Tags: java, url, uri, slash

If I run a webapp under the uri `/myapp` then as soon as the app is accessed via `http://example.com/myapp`, the URL changes to `http://example.com/myapp/`. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: This is browser behavior I think. Which browser are you accessing your app with ?

Comment: Is this a problem for you? why?

Comment: @Simeon: greuze's answer describes what is happening.

Comment: @MarcoS: I would like it to be cleaner and less revealing, also save one of the redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have such a behaviour your web (or application) server returns a

```
301 Moved Permanently
```

when the URL without slash is requested.

You can see a similar example when getting http://www.google.es/services

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.es/services/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Wed, 11 May 2011 15:24:06 GMT
Expires: Fri, 10 Jun 2011 15:24:06 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: sffe
Content-Length: 227
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

After this first HTTP get to http://www.google.es/services
 (without slash), the browser makes a second HTTP get to http://www.google.es/services/ (with slash). You can trace the HTTP requests with Network tab in Firebug, for example.

You can check your web/application server configuration, and maybe you can change this behaviour.

Comment: I understand the behavior. I am asking if this can be configured done on the webapp level of configuration.

Comment: You have to configure it *before* the web application level, that is in the web/application server (in Apache Web Server, Tomcat, IIS, etc.). If you are using an application server behind a web server, you must check both, to check if any is doing the redirection. What server are you using?
You can also redirect the request in your webapp, but I think that is not what you want.

Comment: I was just wanting the trailing slash not to be added at all, but I did not want to change this behavior for the whole server. If this extra redirect could be eliminated using the webapp config, level I wanted to know, but it is looking like that is not possible.